# How to center multiple divs inside div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I tried to center multiple divs (whole block of divs) inside another div/html document, but I failed every time I tried something I found here on StOv.

Here is a pic of what I'm trying to do.

[image: first top situation is what I have right now and the bottom one is what I´d like to do.]

Edit:

I am sorry but, I am using nested jQuery and it is too complex for jsfiddle, only I can do is link to files I am using: http://goo.gl/3kXjK9

Here is my code:

```
<div id="device" style="position: relative; height: 971px; width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">


    <div class="box size42" data-box="0" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="1" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="2" data-width="107" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 107px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="3" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="4" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="5" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="6" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size62" data-box="7" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="8" data-width="107" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 107px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="9" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="10" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="11" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="12" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="13" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="14" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 107px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="15" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="16" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="17" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 35px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="18" data-width="35" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 35px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="19" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 71px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    <div class="box size22" data-box="20" data-width="71" style="display: block; position: absolute; width: 71px; height: 107px; top: 0px; left: 0px;" data-y="0" data-x="0"></div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Could you give us a working example in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Exactly. And your code isn't really clean. Best to use a html file like now and use a css file for your styling.

Comment: This is working, you have given `#device` a width of 100% so it is filling the screen. The gap you see on the right is because the grey divs don't fit in that last space and so are wrapping.

Comment: For `margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;` to work like you expect you would need a set static width on that element and you have `width:100%;` which is your problem.

Comment: I am sorry but, I am using nested jqery and it is too complex for jsfiddle, only I can do is link to files I am using: https://goo.gl/3kXjK9

Comment: Are you open to a flexbox solution? http://stackoverflow.com/a/33049198/3597276

Answer (score 1):

By changing the #device CSS:

- Remove the width
- Use auto margins:

```css
#device {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can center it by using the following CSS,

```
#parent {
    position: relative;
    height: 971px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    margin:auto;
    width:100%;
}
```

Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much to go on since there's no live demo, so here's what I did:

- Used [flexbox](https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/), the `#device1` is the flex container and is controlling the children `.box` to center. There are of course alternative ways to arrange them.
- The `#device1` is centered by applying `padding: 10px` to `body`
- Removed all positioning properties which were responsible for showing showing all of the `.box` in one corner.
- Corrected `#device1` attributes that were being written as CSS properties.
- Keep in mind the original dimensions were kept, so each element is at the size you have originally made them as.
- Added another `#device2` to demonstrate the flexbox property of `order`. On the `#device2` the `.box` are each assigned an `order` property and a integer value. The `.box` are arranged accordingly ([but only in appearance, in the DOM they are positioned as they are in the code](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/order/))

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>34593110</title>
  <style>
    html,
    body {
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font: 400 16px/1.45"Verdana";
      height: 100vh;
      width: 100vw;
    }
    *,
    *:before,
    *:after {
      box-sizing: inherit;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      border: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
      outline: 0 none hlsa(0%, 0, 0, 0);
    }
    body {
      position: relative;
      background-color: #111;
      color: #EEE;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    #device {
      display: -webkit-flex;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
      -webkit-justify-content: center;
      justify-content: center;
      -webkit-align-items: center;
      align-items: center;
      -webkit-align-content: center;
      align-content: center;
      outline: 3px dashed red;
      background-color: hsla(0, 100%, 50%, .3);
    }
    .box {
      outline: 1px solid blue;
      background-color: hsla(240, 100%, 50%, .3);
      font-size: 1.2rem;
      text-align: center;
      color: #FF0;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="device" height="971" width="100%" style="margin: 20px auto;">
    <div class="box size42" data-box="0" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">1</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="1" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">2</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="2" data-width="107" style="width: 107px; height: 71px;">3</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="3" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">4</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="4" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">5</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="5" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px;">6</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="6" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">7</div>
    <div class="box size62" data-box="7" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">8</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="8" data-width="107" style="width: 107px; height: 35px;">9</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="9" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px;">10</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="10" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">11</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="11" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">12</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="12" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px;">13</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="13" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">14</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="14" data-width="71" style="width: 107px; height: 71px;">15</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="15" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px;">16</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="16" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px;">17</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="17" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px;">18</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="18" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px;">19</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="19" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px;">20</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="20" data-width="71" style="width: 107px; height: 71px;">21</div>
  </div>

  <div id="device" height="971" width="100%" style="margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto;">
    <div class="box size42" data-box="0" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; order: 11;">1</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="1" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 20;">2</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="2" data-width="107" style="width: 107px; height: 71px; order: 1;">3</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="3" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; order: 12;">4</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="4" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 13;">5</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="5" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px; order: 2;">6</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="6" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 14;">7</div>
    <div class="box size62" data-box="7" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; order: 15;">8</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="8" data-width="107" style="width: 107px; height: 35px; order: 19;">9</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="9" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px; order: 3;">10</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="10" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; order: 16;">11</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="11" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 18;">12</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="12" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px; order: 4;">13</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="13" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 16;">14</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="14" data-width="71" style="width: 107px; height: 71px; order: 9;">15</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="15" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px; order: 5;">16</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="16" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 35px; order: 17;">17</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="17" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 35px; order: 21;">18</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="18" data-width="35" style="width: 35px; height: 71px; order: 7;">19</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="19" data-width="71" style="width: 71px; height: 71px; order: 6;">20</div>
    <div class="box size22" data-box="20" data-width="71" style="width: 107px; height: 71px; order: 10;">21</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```